# install ubuntu on laptop with windows 8 32bit

Tags: windows-8, 32-bit

I saw in the instructions that if I wanted to install ubuntu on my PC wiht withdows 8 i should download the 64 bit version.  My laptop is an older 32 bit laptop that I have put windows 8 on.

Should I use the 32 bit version of Ubuntu instead? I have installed it to a USB drive and I see on there where I can install it WITH my current OS but will this work with Win 8?

Thanks.

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: @Seth - 1. Windows 8 isn't pre-installed, and 2. He doesn't have UEFI Secure Boot.

Comment: @nerof61  I know Windows 8 isn't pre-installed, but he doesn't mention anything about UEFI.  Just because Windows 8 isn't pre-installed doesn't mean he doesn't have UEFI.  In either case, that answer is still helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It should work.

**But if your computer only supports 32-bit, use 32-bit. If it supports 64-bit, then use 64-bit.**

You see, people would ask you to disable the Secure Boot, but as soon as it wasn't pre-installed the it won't have UEFI.

While booted in Windows 8, press the `.iso` file/ Ubuntu image.

At the screen, choose 'Install Ubuntu'.

[image: 1]

Now choose 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8'.

[image: 2,2]

If this screen comes up, choose how much memory you want Ubuntu to have.

[image: 3,3]

Now click 'Install Ubuntu'.

It may come to this screen.

[image: 4,4]

Look at those top tips to get the most out of Ubuntu!

Enjoy!

Comment: You don't address what version of Ubuntu the OP should use:  `32 bit` or `64 bit`.

Comment: @Seth - Done. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should just install the 32-bit version if you are using an older laptop.
When using a 32bit version you can be sure it will work.
I think they we're just assuming you had an 64 bit laptop since you're using such a modern operating system.